# Forward planning heuristics - hmax, hadd, hff

Tags: heuristics, planning

I'm studying the forward planning heuristics hmax, hadd, and hff and I've found some resources online, but I really can't understand how they actually work.

Here the resources I've found so far:

http://icaps09.uom.gr/tutorials/tut1.pdf
(An ICAPS (International Conference on Planning and Scheduling) tutorial 2009 by Emil Keyder & Blai Bonet about "Heuristics For Planning", which explains hmax, hadd, hff, and h+.)

http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/papers/betz-helmert-icaps2009ws.pdf
(A scientific paper by Betz and Helmert, published at the German Converence on AI 2009 with the title "Planning with h+ in Theory and Practice", which is closely related to the other three.)

https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/wiki/_media/courses/a4m36pah/07_relaxation.pdf
(Another tutorial (of unknown source), which is also about the heuristics  hmax, hadd, hff.)

Can you explain in a simpler way how they work?
Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming that you already understand the basic ideas of planning. The **hMax**, **hAdd** and **hFF** algorithms are used to calculate a heuristic value for a given state on the planning graph, relative to the currently occupied state.

All three algorithms work by considering a **relaxed** version of the problem; specifically, a version that has been relaxed by removing the delete list for each applicable action. The effect of this can be summed up as **once an atom is achieved (made true), it stays achieved**.

---

**hMax** and **hAdd** work in very similar ways. The two algorithms work by considering a state in the planning graph, and using all applicable actions to make every atom in that state true. The cost of the actions required to make all atoms true is the basis of the heuristic value they produce.

For **hAdd**, the heuristic for a given state is the **combined cost** of achieving every atom in that state.

For **hMax**, the heuristic for a given state is the cost of the **most expensive** atom in that state.

Note that *neither algorithm actually solves the relaxed problem*, they just compute an estimate of how difficult a given state would be to achieve, relative to the current state.

**hMax is admissible**, whereas **hAdd is not**.

---

**hFF** is different, as it actually solves the relaxed problem. It does not attempt to find an optimal solution (see † below), but rather a solution that is reasonable.

To determine the heuristic of a given state (let's call it *s*), **hFF** finds a solution from the current state to the given state in the relaxed plan, which is often referred to as *π(s)*. Once that solution has been found, the heuristic value given to the state *s* is **the number of actions in the relaxed solution**. This can be written as:

***h(s) = |π(s)|***

**hFF** is sometimes called the **relaxed plan h**. It is **not admissible**, but it is **informative**.

The method used to find a solution in the relaxed plan varies depending on the implementation of the **hFF** algorithm.

† **hFF** doesn't try to find an optimal solution because, whilst easier than planning for the original problem, computing an optimal solution is still **far too difficult** to use as a heuristic because it has to be computed for each state. Instead, it tries to find a *reasonable* plan, which is computationally much less expensive.

---

I really hope this has helped, and that I haven't confused you further.

<del>I also really hope I'm right - I'm relativelty confident that I am, but I am fully open to being corrected.</del> Having had this checked by an AI lecturer, I'm now confident that this is correct.

Comment: Thank you, it confirms what I thought about them!

Comment: Some additional details on the sub-optimality of hFF: hFF just computes a heuristic value for *some* relaxed plan, whereas the heuristic value for the *optimal* relaxed plan is always denoted by h^+. As *Mark Ormesher* mentioned, computing h^+ is harder than just computing some relaxed plan. More precisely: computing hFF can be done in P (polynomial time), whereas computing h^+ is known to be NP-complete (non-deterministic polynomial, i.e., at the time being, the best-known algorithm to tackle any problem of this class requires exponential time in the size of the input).